# Rank of a matrix using quadratic forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, quadratic-forms, representations-by-quadratic-forms

Let $A=(a_{ij})$ be an **invertible** matrix. I would like to study the **rank** of the following matrix
$$M=\Big(a_{ik}a_{jk}\Big)_{1\leq i<j\leq n, 1\leq k\leq n}.$$
For $n=3$ I used the page [Matrix Calculator](https://matrixcalc.org/en/) to compute the determinant of $M=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}a_{21}&a_{11}a_{31}&a_{21}a_{31}\\
a_{12}a_{22}&a_{12}a_{32}&a_{22}a_{32}\\
a_{13}a_{23}&a_{13}a_{33}&a_{23}a_{33}\end{pmatrix}$ and I get a long formula
$$\det M=a_{33}a_{11}a_{12}a_{21}a_{23}a_{32}-a_{12}a_{13}a_{21}a_{23}a_{31}a_{32}+a_{33}a_{12}a_{13}a_{21}a_{31}a_{22}-a_{33}a_{11}a_{12}a_{23}a_{31}a_{22}-\ldots+\ldots$$

> Is it possible to write the determinants $n\times n$, extracted from $M$, using some quadratic forms?

It's related to my question in Mathoverflow
[Degenerate representation](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426554/degenerate-representation)

Comment: As you wrote it, this is not a matrix, as you have three indices. Do you mean $\displaystyle\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_{ik}a_{jk}\right)_{1\leq i,j\leq n}$? In that case, $M=AA^{T}$ so the determinant of $M$ is the square of the determinant of $A$.

Comment: @Andijvie The index $k$ for columns and the pairs $(i,j) i<j$ for rows: $(1,2)$ for the first row,...$(1,n), (2 ,3),...,(2,n),...,(n-1,n)$: $n(n-1)/2$ lines in total.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you would think that quadratic forms are relevant here?

Comment: A great answer is given here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/426554/degenerate-representation